# Pip not working with Python3.6 (Ubuntu 14)

Tags: python, pip

I have a lot of problems that I don't understand with python and its different versions. I am doing a CS50 Web online course, and I need pip3 for python 3.6 or higher. The case is that I can't use pip for python 3.6. 
Under `/usr/local/bin` I can find different pip files: pip, pip2, pip2.7, pip3 and pip3.4. Anyway, if I run "pip" I get the message bash:

> /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python: defect interpreter. File could
>   been not found.

How can I use the pip command in the python3.6 version?
For the course project, I should use `"pip3 install -r requirements.txt"` where requirements.txt has following items:

```
Flask
Flask-Session
psycopg2
SQLAlchemy
```

I tried with `"python3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt"` and I got following message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
>       mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
>       return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
>       **import**(pkg_name)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/**init**.py", line 59, in 
>       from pip.log import logger   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 9, in 
>       import colorama, pkg_resources   File "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File
>   "", line 656, in _load_unlocked   File
>   "", line 626, in
>   _load_backward_compatible   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 1479, in 
>       register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider) AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no
>   attribute 'SourceFileLoader' Error in sys.excepthook: Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in
>   apport_excepthook
>       from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/**init**.py", line 5, in
>   
>       from apport.report import Report   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in
>   
>       import apport.fileutils   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in
>   
>       from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in
>   
>       import apt   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/**init**.py", line 23, in 
>       import apt_pkg ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
>
> Original exception was: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
>       mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
>       return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
>       **import**(pkg_name)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/**init**.py", line 59, in 
>       from pip.log import logger   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 9, in 
>       import colorama, pkg_resources   File "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File
>   "", line 656, in _load_unlocked   File
>   "", line 626, in
>   _load_backward_compatible   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 1479, in 
>       register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider) AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no
>   attribute 'SourceFileLoader' [1]+  Fertig                  gedit
>   requirements.txt

I appreciate any help. Thanks a lot guys!

Carlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be caught in a situation where the pip installed on your system has fallen behind.

If you're using a `virtualenv`, the following might help

```
virtualenv --python=python3 venv
venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thank you Dave W. Smith. The python versions were messed up. I changed before a lot and after removing of two of three python version, Ubuntu didn't work well. I learnt the lection. The solution was to reinstall ubuntu. I had Ubuntu 14, so it was time to install Ubuntu 18, and I love it :) ... Now if I want to use pip3 I run python3 -m pip